# How is it possible that a single address contains 8 bits if each BIT in a memory has its own unique address?

Tags: memory

In the data structure, address 0001 contains 8 bits, then address 0010 is another 8 bits.

But in a RAM memory array, every single bit has its own unique address.

In a RAM, Address 0001 points to a memory cell, and address 0010 points to another memory cell.

So if I input address 0001, Why is it possible to point to 8 bits, not just 1?

How is **byte addressability** possible in a memory array like this? [image](https://i.imgur.com/OnMvj2n.jpg)

It has to take a row and column address just to select a single memory cell.

I don't understand how byte addressability is possible here.

Comment: Row and column still works on byte boundaries, you just have an 8-bit block at each selectable address and then pass them out as a group. I've actually designed circuits that use DDR chips (not DIMMs) so I've actually seen what happens. For every selectable address an entire byte will appear at the DDR chip going to the processor, and it will be read in parallel, you just see it as a series of ones and zeroes because you "know" that one bit follows another.

Comment: @Mokubai is this what you mean by parallel? https://imgur.com/a/g1U8kIQ

Comment: Essentially yes. Within the memory chip you have 8 blocks which are connected to the same address, the result is that any given address puts out a full byte on the data lines.

Comment: @Mokubai thank you. I want to know more about this concept, but I'm not sure what search terms I should type on Google. Could you help me about this?

Comment: Honestly the better thing to look at is a [DDR memory datasheet](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/2gb_1_35v_ddr3l.pdf?rev=4a2dca2a48b042fc92188aad62656cec). It shows x4, x8 and x16 chips which would denote 4-bit, 8-bit and 16-bit wide data ports (DQ lines). you would combine individual chips up to make an 8,16 or 32-bit wide data bus. There are many sources on the internet. I searched https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ddr+memory+address+mapping and found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xtWsQvOcjo that looks useful.

Answer (score 2):

> In the data structure, address 0001 contains 8 bits, then address 0010 is another 8 bits.

The concept of a "*data structure*" exists typically only in software, i.e. a programming language, and is not typically supported by the hardware. The elements of a "*data structure*" would be referenced by symbolic names rather than numeric addresses (of some unspecified radix).

Instead of a "*data structure*" did you really mean an *array*, which would be indexed by a numeric value? But an array does not have to be of just bytes. You could define an array of 32-bit signed integers.

Whatever example or point you're trying to make doesn't make sense.

---

> But in a RAM memory array, every single bit has its own unique address.

That's an incorrect statement.
The size of the data referenced by a RAM address depends on the hardware system or CPU architecture. Since I used to program minicomputers in the 1970s that had 16-bit words and non-volatile, ferrite core RAM, I do not presume that RAM is byte addressable nor RAM is volatile (which are two attributes practically universal in a modern computer).

---

> In a RAM, Address 0001 points to a memory cell, and address 0010 points to another memory cell.

First of all, what radix are these "*addresses*"?

> So if I input a 0001 address, Why is it possible to point to 8 bits, not just 1?

Because on the typically computer that was ever built (AFAIK), a memory address referenced either a word (as defined for that CPU architecture) or a byte. The utility of referencing each individual bit in memory is overwhelmed by the need to have the address space access as much memory as possible.

Do not ignore the influence of history.
Historically hardware has been expensive. The memory address size is often constrained by the expense of a fast and wide parallel address bus. The 16-bit words of 1970s minicomputers (e.g. DEC PDP-11, DG Nova, HP 2100) are a prefect example of such a compromise. The availability of modern, inexpensive, 64-bit processors does not really mean that memory addresses will become bit addresses instead of byte (or word) addresses.

For instance, the Program Counter (register of the CPU) would contain the memory address of the next instruction to execute. Those instructions are probably stored in memory with word alignment. There's no utility in having bit-address-ability for more than half of the memory accesses performed by the CPU (i.e. fetching instructions).

---

> How is **byte addressability** possible in a memory array like this? [image](https://i.imgur.com/OnMvj2n.jpg)
>
> It has to take a row and column address just to select a single memory cell.
>
> I don't understand how byte addressability is possible here.

You seem to be confused by the memory subsystem interface (which may involve an 8-, 16-, 32-, 64-, or 128-bit data transfer to the CPU) with the internal organization of the memory subsystem. You can try to deduce the data transfer width, or you need to determine/specify what kind of memory subsystem you're looking at to understand how the bits of the memory address (plus row & column signals) are utilized or discarded to access the memory chips/array.

Answer (score 1):

While every bit has it's own address in RAM, reads and writes must be done on byte boundaries.

There were (if I remember correctly) processors that allowed bit-addressing, but most modern processors use byte addressing as a method of increasing memory size as you can discard the lower 3 bits of an address needed for bit-addressing. The result is that instead of 4,294,967,296 *bits* (= 536,870,912 bytes = 524,288 kilobytes = 512 megabytes) you can now address 4,294,967,296 *bytes* = 4 gigabytes.